# vuejs not able to use data from useMutation on template => async problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, apollo-client, gql

I'm using a mutation from gql with vue apollo in the front tom get some data, there's a number and an Email.
Once mutation is finished, I assign the value to refs:

```
const mobile = ref('')
    const email = ref('')
    // mutation logic:
    const {
      mutate: getContactInfo,
      onDone,
      onError
    } = useMutation(
      gql`
        mutation ContactInfo($userId: String!) {
          contactInfo(userId: $userId) {
            mobile
            email
          }
        }
      `,
      () => ({
        variables: {
          userId: props.userID
        }
      })
    )
    onDone(data => {
      const res = data
      mobile.value = res.data.contactInfo.mobile
      email.value = res.data.contactInfo.email
    })
```

down this code I got these next 2 functions:

```
    const emailContact = async () => {
      loading.value = true
      await getContactInfo()
      location.replace(`mailto:${email.value}`)
      loading.value = false
    }

    const smsContact = async () => {
      loading.value = true
      await getContactInfo()
      location.href = `sms:${mobile.value.slice(1)}`
      loading.value = false
    }
```

Both work well except that the vanilla js method =>  `location.replace(`mailto:${email.value}`)` is causing me issues on mobile devices while I can do the same with a <a / HTML  tag and have no problems.

So my problem is that once I want to send the email ref to the template so I can fire the mailto:'  ' from an <a / tag **the data is not there**. *Even when I make a console.log(email.value) => I just see a blank line.*
I mean, I know the data is there and that's why I can use both previous methods, but why can't I use it on the template or log it. Seems like an asynchronous issue.

Of course, thanks in advance && any suggestion/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Means that onDone runs after getContactInfo ends, I suppose it's a mistake to use it here. If you rely on a specific sequence, create a function that contains both `await getContactInfo()` and the content of onDone

Comment: I did exactly that thinking it was a strange/ would work approach, and it worked, thanks bro!